# JScript error in XVal, Has anybody seen this error?

Tags: plugins, javascript, xval

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'this.Plugins[...]' is null or not an object

coming from this code:

```
var xVal = xVal || {
    Plugins: {},
    AttachValidator: function(elementPrefix, rulesConfig, pluginName) {
        if (pluginName != null)
            this.Plugins[pluginName].AttachValidator(elementPrefix, rulesConfig);
        else
            for (var key in this.Plugins) {
                this.Plugins[key].AttachValidator(elementPrefix, rulesConfig);
                return;
            }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are referencing **xVal.AspNetNative.js** AND **xVal.jquery.validate.js** in your master page.